# Ninject 2 missing RegisterAllControllersln?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm totally a newbie with `Ninject` and I tried to follow the tutorial by Shiju Varghese at [his blog post about DI](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/04/30/dependency-injection-in-nerddinner-app-using-ninject.aspx).

I did add reference of ninject.dll and Ninject.Web.Mvc.dll
However, I got stuck as Visual Studio cannot resolve the function RegisterAllControllersIn....

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    // RegisterAllControllersIn could not be found!!
    RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

I'm using `Visual Studio 2010 Prof`, `.Net 4`, `MVC2`, [Ninject 2.0.0.0 / 2.0.1.0](http://github.com/ninject/ninject/downloads) and [Ninject Web.mvc extension](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc)

Answer (score 7):

Based on the [README for ninject.web.mvc](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc) it appears that the line

RegisterAllControllersIn(..)

is only needed for ASP.NET MVC 1

Comment: how do you register controllers from other assemblies now? Does that work automatically as well?

Answer (score 1):

`RegisterAllControllersIn` lives in `Ninject.Web.MvcNinjectHttpApplication`

You probably are not deriving your MVC application / global class from `MvcApplication` [instead of `HttpApplication` or similar].

Best way of searching stuff like this is to stick MVC, Ninject and Ninject.MVC into Reflector and do an F3-search